# build conda package from local python package

Tags: python, package, conda

I can't find a complete example of how to create a conda package from a python package that I wrote and also how to install the package using conda install, while it is on my computer and not on anaconda cloud.
I'm looking for example that not using conda skeleton from pypi, but using a python package on my windows machine, the source code must be on my windows machine and not on pypi or other cloud.
any help would be mostly appriciate.
thanks very much

Comment: I usually make a directory called `conda.recipe` in the source directory and use this `meta.yaml` file template: https://github.com/bryanwweber/UConnRCMPy/blob/master/conda.recipe/meta.yaml Disclaimer: That is some software that I'm the author of. I'll try to write a fuller example when I get the time

Comment: Then you can build the package by writing (from the main source directory) `conda build conda.recipe` and then to install `conda install --use-local`. If you want to skip the package building altogether and just install the package as a development version, similar to `pip -e`, you can use `conda develop .`

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: can you please share your setup.py script you are using for this example?

Comment: In the same repository: https://github.com/bryanwweber/UConnRCMPy/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: did you try any of the solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474575/how-to-install-my-own-python-module-package-via-conda-and-watch-its-changes ?

Comment: Why everything in python has to be so confusing and complicated? :-/

Answer (score 7):

I think it should be trivial if you use the editable way to install packages with conda. I did:

```
conda develop .
```

in the project directory (where my `setup.py` file is).

If you want an example of a `setup.py` here is mine:

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools import find_packages

setup(
    name='ml', #project name
    version='0.1.0',
    description='ML',
    #url
    author='Me',
    author_email='charlie_parker@mit.edu', #not a real e-mail
    license='MIT',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=['torch','numpy','scikit-learn','scipy','matplotlib','pyyml']
)
```

The file above is at the root of the project (I do a github repo named `project` and inside I make a project `project` with all the packages I develop there.

I believe `pip -e .` will do the same. You shouldn't need to sudo anything.

Answer (score 4):

A local source directory can be specified in the metadata file meta.yaml by using:

```
  source:
     path: ../src
```

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#source-from-a-local-path

Additionally, to package your own program you have to define the steps needed to build and install it (for instance, running setup.py install for a python script that uses setuptools: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) in the files build.sh for linux and bld.bat for windows.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `python setup.py bdist_conda` to easily generate a conda package from your local python package, even without a recipe:

> You can use conda build to build packages for Python to install rather than conda, by using setup.py bdist_conda. This is a quick way to build packages without using a recipe, but it has limitations. The script is limited to the Python version used in the build, and it is not as reproducible as using a recipe. We recommend using a recipe with conda build.

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/recipes/build-without-recipe.html

Answer (score 0):

I found some helpful information on the [Anaconda Enterprise](https://enterprise-docs.anaconda.com/en/latest/data-science-workflows/packages/build.html) doc. The two videos linked:

- [The Sheer Joy of Packaging | SciPy 2018 Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xiI1i525ljE&feature=youtu.be&t=9015) There is A LOT of fluff, but the meat of it is about 2hr30min (link is timestamped)
- <s>[Michael Sarahan - Making packages and packaging "just work"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kamld5Z-xx0)</s>

are the best things I found in my searching.